# Dialog box as a additional working box

Tags: javascript, dialog, box

I want to create an dialog box in javascript (with Jquery or without) that lets you click normaly on the background items and you can add into dialog box some inputs, buttons...etc.

For example like those smaller tools boxes in Photoshop that you can drag and resize them anywhere.

My question is, is it even possible to do this? 
Because i saw only cases of alert, dialog and prompt boxes, and thats it.

Comment: You can use a `div` with `z-index` set.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.
I was able to do this with this example: http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/Xcb8d/light/

Any idea how to limit the div, so you cant drag it outside website?